# Flutter ios Google Authentification without firebase error

Tags: flutter, google-authentication, flutter-ios

I'm trying to set up my app without firebase services, but I've faced the issue with Google Authentification. The error message is following: `Runner[9138:3105633] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(missing-config, GoogleService-Info.plist file not found, null, null)`
Is it possible to use Google auth without the firebase?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No!** There is no way to use Google auth without the firebase, you must integrated your app with firebase.

Comment: I've created a project in firebase and downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist without activating Google auth for the project and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Vanfen, could you please share some resources on how to do that?

Comment: Hey @Santiago, missed the notification, sorry. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Well I ended up having to integrate my project with firebase for push notifications, it worked once but then I had to delete it and do it the firebase way, I can't remember exactly how I did it but I feel like there was a Second hand Google Auth flutter package that would help you do it.